# How to arrange posts from different models in Order of time when they were created

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

**Intro:** I have a 3 models `user`, `post`, `group`. User is able to make posts however each post has to belong to a group. I have 400 fixed groups. Users have to choose from the existing 400 groups for their posts. Users cannot add, delete, update `group`'s.

**Furthermore:**

Users can become a member of groups and when they click on a certain group. They see all the posts in that group.

Users can follow-unfollow other users.

**What I have right now:**When a user signs-in. In his home page he sees. All the posts of the each individual group he is a member of. When all the posts from all the groups are done with. He then sees the posts of all the people he follows one by one

**What I want:** I want the **posts to be arranged by time** 
Example: If one of the people he follows *just wrote a post* then that post is first. Chronologically the second post was in one of the groups that he is a member of. That post comes second... You get the idea

**Below are my models**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupMember')
```

**my views.py**

```
class Homepage(TemplateView):
template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Homepage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        posts_of_people_i_follow = []
        posts_from_groups_that_i_member = []
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            my = self.request.user
            for user in my.following.all():
                posts_of_people_i_follow += user.posts.all()
                posts_of_people_i_follow.save()
            for group in my.group_set.all():
                posts_from_groups_that_i_member += group.posts.all()
                posts_from_groups_that_i_member.save()            
        context['posts_of_people_I_follow_list'] = posts_of_people_i_follow
        context['posts_from_groups_that_i_member'] = posts_from_groups_that_i_member
        return context
```

In my **Templates** I currently have

```
{% for post in posts_from_groups_that_i_member %}
  {{ post.title }}
  {{ post.message }}
{% endfor %}

{% for post in posts_of_people_I_follow_list %}
  {{ post.title }}
  {{ post.message }}
{% endfor %}
```

> Option 2: After breaking my head on this for a while I have been trying a different approach. But this looks really expensive

**In the user profile model**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_all_posts(self):
        my = self.user
        all_posts_for_this_user = []
        for user in my.following.all():
            all_posts_for_this_user += user.posts.all()
            all_posts_for_this_user.save()
        for group in my.group_set.all():
            all_posts_for_this_user += group.posts.all()
            all_posts_for_this_user.save()
         return all_posts_for_this_user
```

**Then in my templates**

```
 {% for post in user.profile.get_all_posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.message }}
 {% endfor %}
```

> Can anyone think of a better solution. Or is this ok

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly, you need post date in your Post model then you can order posts by  Post.objects.ordey_by('post_date')

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

Comment: I am sorry I actually have that in my models. I just removed it when I edited my models to simplify them

Comment: Also this will arrange them chronologically from 1 group. Example If I did `Post.objects.all` the posts will arrange chronologically. But in my case. We are taking the posts list from different places. Example. lets imagine there are 3 groups. The the forloop will show all the posts in 1 group chronologically. Then the posts of the second group. After it finishes posts from all groups, It will start showings posts of 1st followed user chronologically. then the next user...

Comment: can you add some screenshots of your homepage please?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your view class by using an 'order_by()' method on the queryset that fetches your post objects and filters them according to when they were created (The 'created_at' field comes in handy here).

Add this to your 'Homepage' view class:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        queryset_list = Post.objects.order_by('-created_at')
```

Further reading can be found here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/



**EDIT**
I think the template rendering issue deserves its own question?

In your template, try this:

```
{% for post in posts_from_groups_that_i_member %}
    {% if post in posts_of_people_I_follow_list %}
        {{ post.title }}
        {{ post.message }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In terms of performance, it may not be the best option but it should work. Let me know your findings.

Comment: Any idea how this will look in the template

Comment: Currently I am choosing `posts_of_people_I_follow_list` and `posts_from_groups_that_i_member` in my templates to get the posts

Comment: You can use if/else statements to achieve what you want. Can you post that block of markup in your template?